# awk-convert first 2 lines to first row and next 2 lines to second row and so on

Tags: awk, row

I would like to convert first 2 lines to first row and next 2 lines to second row and so on.
Could someone help me? .would it possible to do by awk command.

File.txt has the below entries

```
Bin1
Bin2
Hex3
Hex4 
oct5
oct6
```

I would like to get output as below

```
Bin1  Bin2
Hex3 Hex4
oct5 oct6
```

Comment: Does your input file really have blank lines like that? Do you want to keep the inter-pair blank lines (if the input does have them)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '{ORS=(NR%2?FS:RS)}1' file
Bin1 Bin2
Hex3 Hex4
oct5 oct6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
awk 'NR%2{printf "%s%s",$0,OFS}NR%2==0' file
```

Output:

```
Bin1 Bin2
Hex3 Hex4 
oct5 oct6
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `xargs`:

```
$ xargs -n2 < file                                                          
Bin1 Bin2
Hex3 Hex4
oct5 oct6
```

Or `paste`:

```
$ paste -d' ' - - < file
Bin1 Bin2
Hex3 Hex4
oct5 oct6
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution by sed

```
sed '$!N;s/\n/ /' file
```